# How to unit test MassTransit request response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, masstransit

I am trying to test a method that calls Masstransit Request

```
public async Task<EventsPingCompleted> SendPing()
{
  _logger.LogInformation($"Sending Events Ping");
  var message = new EventsPing();
  var response = await _bus.Request<EventsPing, EventsPingCompleted>(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return response.Message;
}
```

I want to return a specific response as part of my unit test. To do this I created a stubbed consumer because I don't want to unit test the consumer, I am doing that in other tests.

```
public  class StubbedConsumer<T,TRt>: IConsumer<T> where T : class where TRt : class
{
    private readonly TRt _response;

    public StubbedConsumer( TRt expectedResponse )
    {
        _response = expectedResponse;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
      await context.RespondAsync<TRt>(_response).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

My unit test is passing but when I debug it the stubbed consumer is being called in my unit test.

```
[Fact]
public async Task SendPing_GetResponse()
{
  // Arrange
  var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
  var expectedResult = new EventsPingCompleted();
  var startEvent = new EventsPing();

  // the harness needs a consumer for request to work
  harness.Consumer(() => new StubbedConsumer<EventsPing, EventsPingCompleted>(expectedResult));
  await harness.Start();

  // helper needs to be after harness is started
  var helper = new PingHelper(harness.BusControl, _logger.Object);

  //connect a request client
  var requestClient = await harness.ConnectRequestClient<EventsPing>().ConfigureAwait(false);

  // Act
  // this configures the response, these 2 are equivalent but without calling get response on the request client the tests time out
  // when both are called the StubbedConsumer is called twice
  var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<EventsPingCompleted>(startEvent);
  var result = await helper.SendPing().ConfigureAwait(false);

  try
  {
    // Assert
    Assert.True(harness.Sent.Select<EventsPing>().Any());
    Assert.True(harness.Consumed.Select<EventsPingCompleted>().Any());

    Assert.Equal(expectedResult.Time, result.Time);
    Assert.Equal(expectedResult.Time, response.Message.Time);
  }
  finally
  {
    await harness.Stop();
  }
}
```

The first message is dispatched by

```
var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<EventsPingCompleted>(startEvent);
```

And then the second happens in my system under test

```
var result = await helper.SendPing().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If I remove the call `requestClient.GetResponse()` the SUT times out without receiving the response from the stubbed consumer.

Is there a way that I can configure the request client without calling `GetResponse` so that I'm not sending 2 events?

Comment: The request client is designed to send requests and receive responses. When you pass the message in the call to GetResponse(), that's sending and waiting for the response. You can **not** send the message from some other place and receive the response.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, so then is the correct response to Mock IBusControl? Then my issue would be how to mock the correct MessageResponse to return my completed event?